# How to make search engines crawl and index dynamic AJAX pages?

Tags: seo, url, search-engines, dynamic, crawlable-ajax

I have a following website with some products: http://www.lay-z.net/beanbags.php

When a user clicks on a product it makes a call to the database and fills the site with necessary information: http://www.lay-z.net/product.php#Darling-Premium

But this link is dynamic and when I search for this product in lets say google search, it doesn't get listed in the results.

Is there a way to make this content indexed by search engines?

Comment: This is a big topic.   The answer would not fit in a few paragraphs.   To get started look up "crawlable AJAX" and "push state".

Answer (score 0):

If you want a page to be indexed you need to change something in the URL that distinguishes it from the rest, so a search engine can refer to it directly.

In the case of dynamic pages the common practice is to change the parameters of the url.

For example in the page `example.com/page.php` If the content changes after some user interaction you can add a parameter `example.com/page.php?content=other` that will be enough for a SE to be able to index it.

Comment: But the url is already changed - I added a hashtag and the name of the product: product.php#Darling-Premium

Comment: @mirta what happens after you send that to google it search console? Or add that URL to your sitemap too

Comment: I have added it to the sitemap 4-5 hours ago.  And When I try to fetch it as google in search console, it just removes the #something and redirects to products.php